# Fetching external data into SharePoint online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, api, external-data

Is it possible to get data from external sources into SharePoint online sites? I suppose rest API's is an option, but how can that be done? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not SharePoint that limits what you can import.

You need to connect to the API of your 3rd party vendor.
If they don't "*let you in*", you can't get the data

So start by investigating if the vendor has APIs, then follow their code examples.

To import content into SharePoint learn to use the SharePoint REST endpoints, or use the Microsoft PnP tools: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP

Comment: Yes they are providing with API's. But to import content what REST API's will i use? Any tutorial, walkthrough ?

Comment: People don't like your answers that tell people how to find answers themselves.  It's kinda sad.  I downvoted this question as it's something that really should've been solved by Google.

Comment: I know, and I won't stop my sometimes blunt comments.. I am good at memorizing names; so if people don't learn I will never answer any question they ask again. Before asking a question on SO one should have at least searched for 15 minutes. If it where up to me questions should include at least 3 urls with information that kinda helped but didn't answer the question.

Comment: After all this @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I just have to say your answer helped me a lot. And I have started getting idea of how to import external data into SharePoint. Please do not interpret me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online we can setup BCS - Business Connectivity Service and get external data in SharePoint Online List.

What is your external data source?

Comment: a third party tool like Connectwise.

Comment: What if we wish to copy data from an external excel sheet to a SharePoint List?

Comment: You can create SharePoint List from excel. So all data will be imported in SharePoint Online.

Comment: BCS cannot connect to Connectwise tool. If you have any web service then BCS can connect.

Comment: Well Connectwise will be providing us with set of API's to access data from their system. In that case?

Comment: In BCS we can connect with SQL Azure Data base and WCF Service.